# How to write this Stored Procedure to return many row as a single string

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have one Stored Procedure. I just wanted to concatenate many row values into single string. Also the end result needs to return one row with a certain column to be the concatenation of all the row values as string. I tried the below code. But it throwing an error. Please help me to find the problem.

**Code**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_getjobdetails] (@jobID INT, 
                                       @foos  VARCHAR(max)) 
--,@l varchar(max),@ts varchar(max)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
  --select @en as int 
  --select @l as l.Location 
  --select @ts as ts.TechnicalSkills 
  SELECT jobcode, 
         jobtitle, 
         experiences, 
         (SELECT @foos = COALESCE(@foos + ',', '') 
                         + e.educationname 
          FROM   tbleducation 
          WHERE  educationid = je.educationid) AS Edu, 
         l.location,--=COALESCE( @l + ', ', '') + l.Location, 
         ts.technicalskills, 
         --=COALESCE ( @ts + ', ', '' )+ ts.TechnicalSkills,  
         jobdescription 
  FROM   tbljobs j 
         INNER JOIN tbljobs_education je 
                 ON je.jobid = j.jobid 
         INNER JOIN tbljobs_locations jl 
                 ON jl.jobid = j.jobid 
         INNER JOIN tbljobs_technicalskill jts 
                 ON jts.jobid = j.jobid 
         INNER JOIN tbleducation e 
                 ON e.educationid = je.educationid 
         INNER JOIN tbllocations l 
                 ON l.locationid = jl.locationid 
         INNER JOIN tbltechnicalskills ts 
                 ON ts.technicalskillid = jts.technicalskillid 
  WHERE  j.jobid = @jobID 
  END
```

**tbljobs tbl**

```
JobCode   JobTitle Experience    Edu       Location        Description
PITCS41   JDev     12-14      BSC,BCA,MSC    Delhi      Asp.Net A highly
```

I need something like the above result.

Comment: shall we guess the error?

Comment: You should give a sample result which your are expecting? Currently, we are not sure what is problem you getting so far?

Comment: Please provide a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your error is that the subquery returns multiple results. Or trying a get data and edit a variable at the same time.

Try the following:

```
SELECT jobcode, 
         jobtitle, 
         experiences, 
         STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + e.educationname 
            FROM   tbleducation 
            WHERE  educationid = je.educationid
            FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 2, '')  AS Edu, 
         l.location,
         ts.technicalskills, 
         jobdescription 
  FROM   tbljobs j 
         INNER JOIN tbljobs_education je 
                 ON je.jobid = j.jobid 
         INNER JOIN tbljobs_locations jl 
                 ON jl.jobid = j.jobid 
         INNER JOIN tbljobs_technicalskill jts 
                 ON jts.jobid = j.jobid 
         INNER JOIN tbleducation e 
                 ON e.educationid = je.educationid 
         INNER JOIN tbllocations l 
                 ON l.locationid = jl.locationid 
         INNER JOIN tbltechnicalskills ts 
                 ON ts.technicalskillid = jts.technicalskillid 
  WHERE  j.jobid = @jobID
```

Next time it would help to give the error message. Since I have no idea if this was your problem for sure.